# Google Analytics - two visitors between August 13th and September 12th

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

So I was recently given access to our Google Analytics, and it appears like we only had TWO visitors between August 13th and September 12th... this is for a site that typically has between several hundred to over a thousand visitors per month.

What could have caused this error? Almost certainly we didn't only have two users during this month.

Answer (score 3):

This could be due to a number of things. We will probably need more information.  Here are some simple things for starters:

- Is the tracking code correctly included on every single page?
- Is there any other JavaScript on the page that could be interfering with the tracking code?
- Are there any errors in the server/application logs?

Answer (score 1):

Also check whether any Filters are active on the Web Property Profile.